# Add multiple users to Google Drive folder through Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a list of email addresses and want to grant them access to a Google Drive folder through Google Drive API. I pass the email address as variable and pass to the create permission array. But the error occurs saying that the email address is not valid. I used print_r() to check the email address and it is correct. The following is the code I used in PHP.

```
$batch = $driveService->createBatch();

// read files containing multiple email address
$myfile = fopen("emaillist.csv","r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$emailList = fread($myfile, filesize("emaillist.csv"));
fclose($myfile);    
$emailListArray = explode(";", $emailList);

$index = 1;
foreach($emailListArray as $email) {

  $userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    'type' => 'user',
    'role' => 'reader'
    'emailAddress' => $email
  ));

  $request = $driveService->permissions->create($fileId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
  $batch->add($request, 'user'.$index);

  $index++;
}
$results = $batch->execute();
```

Any one can guide me what is wrong in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to trim the email address to remove extra spaces. 
ie. 'emailAddress' => $email
After that, it works.

Comment: Correction: ie. 'emailAddress' => trim($email)